# How to achieve this layout with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve something like this:

[image: Look at my awesome 'mockuping' skills]

- A) Is an square image, say 65x65.
- B) This icon is another image which
  need to be floated inside A.
- C) The minimum length of the row is
  the height of A. The maximum depends
  of the length of the text
  description.

Usually when I have floating images like A and B, I would put my container `position` as `relative`, and `obsolute` for the floating image, and that will do it, but I'm a little lost with the text here.

This is just going to be used on webkit browsers, if that is of any use.

Comment: What is going wrong with it? Do you have an example?

Comment: Just on webkit... that indeed helps! But it would help even more if you put the code you have so far, both html and css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the image size is fixed and unlikely to change in the future, then I'd recommend applying position absolute to the image (what you're saying). I'm guessing your problem is that if the text is too short, the height of the image would exceed the height of the container. This is easily fixable with min-height:

```
.module {
    min-height: 65px; /*your image height*/
 }
```

You can view a demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/RkeJJ/

This should work all the way down to IE7.

If your image size is variable, then I'd recommend display: table/table-row/table-cell, but this will work only on IE8+ and the rest of the modern browsers.

*Me debes una caña!* ;)

Comment: Yup this did it. Thanks Mark :) (scary little world!)

Answer (score 1):

You know the width of image A (the large image).  The title goes in a `h1` for example, and the text in a `p` (or `div`), so set these two elements to have **a left margin greater than the width of image A**.

You can then float image A to the left and position the icon B over the image using absolute positioning.

Finally, I would have a wrapper `div` with `overflow: auto` to have a border (if needed) and to allow for a bottom margin to provide white space between the following element.

**Partial answer:** see my code snippet at http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Nam52/

You just need to add the date element after the title.